# Splitting a string into a list1

Tags: python, string, list

I have this:

```
["400,300"]
```

But I want to split into a list, like this:

```
[400,300]
```

How can I do it? I have tried this:

```
gf = ['400,300']
gf = str(gf)
gf = gf.replace("'", "")
gf = gf.replace('"', '')
gf.split(',')
```

Which gives:

```
'[400,300]'
```

Comment: Something like this: `list(map(lambda x: int(x), gf[0].split(",")))` ? Although I think you might  have meant `gf="400,300"` in which case you'd just need `gf.split(",")`

Comment: `list( map( int , gf[0].split(",") ) )`

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[int(x) for x in gf[0].split(',')]
```

First take the first value of `gf` by using `gf[0]`, then split it on the comma `.split(',')`, next loop through all the values returned by the split function with `x for x in gf[0].split(',')`, then cast the `x` variable to an integer with `int(x)` and finally put it all in a list with the brackets `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
gf=['400,300']
gf[0].split(',')
```

Since your `'400,300'` is in a list we must take `gf[0]` to access the first element, then split it into 2 pieces at the `,`

If you are looking for integers at the end you could try this instead:

```
gf=['400,300']
[int(x) for x in gf[0].split(',')]
```

Comment: then convert to integers

Comment: This outputs ['400', '300'] not the [400,300] which OP wants.
You need to convert from str to int in an additional step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
gf=['400,300']
gf = gf[0].split(',')
gf = [int(x) for x in gf]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with nested list comphrensions:

```
gf=['400,300']
gf = [int(splitted_item) for item in gf for splitted_item in item.split(',')]
```

Giving:

```
[400, 300]
```